# Runtime compilation in Java

Tags: java

I have started porting my server side C# app to Java. One of the things it does is dynamic generation of code using the CodeDOM framework, compiling it to bytecode, and loading the class during runtime. There are also scenarios where we have used Expression Tree for lightweight dynamic generation of methods.

I did some research and I believe the closest I came is Javaassist. I would appreciate if there are any other frameworks that supports dynamic code generation and compilation. I am a fresh recruit in the Java world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the Java Compilation API (for example, http://www.accordess.com/wpblog/an-overview-of-java-compilation-api-jsr-199/).

If you just need to evaluate expressions, consider any EL, like OGNL or MVEL.

Groovy, JRuby, and Scala are the most mainstream dynamic languages that allow a huge range of options, from simple expression evaluation to full-blown Java interaction.

Answer (score 0):

To modify classes, you can use javaassit, asm, cglib(actually, it depends on asm), bcel, and etc.
Among them, I recommend asm， because of its better lightweight and better performance.

Using asm, you can generate some classes dynamically. But if you want to modify the classes, which are running in the jvm, you have to use Java Instrument API to retransform the existed classes.

You can see this paper for more info. http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/pohjalai/k05/okk/seminar/Aarniala-instrumenting.pdf

More doc about Instrument from oracle.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/instrumentation/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used [Janino](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home) for dynamic code generation. Like Javassist, it can compile Java source code in-memory. Also like Javassist, it lacks Java 1.5 language features, but apart from that it is easy to use.

The [SimpleCompiler](http://dist.codehaus.org/janino/javadoc/org/codehaus/janino/SimpleCompiler.html) class is a good starting point.

Answer (score -1):

I would look at lisp (or other dynamic languages) that have been targeted to jvm.
[wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages)